# Plot chart using values from richTextBox C#

Tags: c#, charts, plot, gps, richtextbox

is it possible to plot graphs of data that are collected from a richTextBox? For example I have following text in richTextBox:

```
$GPRMC,152908.00,A,5307.0794359,N,02308.8918827,E,0.049,188.6,280612,0.0,E,D*3A
$GPRMC,152909.00,A,5307.0794307,N,02308.8918792,E,0.081,193.3,280612,0.0,E,D*3A
$GPRMC,152910.00,A,5307.0794343,N,02308.8918811,E,0.034,42.9,280612,0.0,E,D*0F
$GPRMC,152911.00,A,5307.0794410,N,02308.8918827,E,0.099,1.3,280612,0.0,E,D*30
$GPRMC,152912.00,A,5307.0794461,N,02308.8918808,E,0.055,331.9,280612,0.0,E,D*32
```

And I want plot chart for example Latitude(time):

```
5307.0794359 -> 152908.00
5307.0794307 -> 152909.00
5307.0794343 -> 152910.00
5307.0794410 -> 152911.00
5307.0794461 -> 152912.00
```

I dont how to write a function, that will retrieve Latitude from lines[1,2,3,4,5] and time from lines [1,2,3,4,5]. And then plot a chart.

I need a universal function, because I can have data which 100 lines or 400 lines etc.

Can anyone help me? Counts for me any help (code, example, tips or links).

Comment: There are 1000 ways to do this. What have you tried? String parsing is simple. DataSets may help you. OxyPlot is a good charting library. http://oxyplot.codeplex.com/

Comment: Hey, I have data on SD Card in .txt format from GPS (frame NMEA), and I need to plot line graph which values (axes Y - Latitude, axes X - time). I writing a program to decomposition GPS frame.

Comment: I have a lot of code for my program but I dont know how to start with this chart. Thanks for reply, I'm searching help for Your tips :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that:

- `richTextBox` is an instance of the `System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox` class;
- `chart` is an instance of the `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart` class.

The following method is intended for parsing an array of `string`s:

```
private static readonly CultureInfo EnglishCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");

private static Tuple<double, double>[] GetData(string[] lines)
{
    return Array.ConvertAll(lines, line =>
        {
            string[] elems = line.Split(',');
            return new Tuple<double, double>(double.Parse(elems[3], EnglishCulture), double.Parse(elems[1], EnglishCulture));
        });
}
```

Usage:

```
var data = GetData(richTextBox.Lines);
```

Now you only need to bind this `data` array as a chart's `DataSource` or manually add them to the series as shown below:

```
chart.Series.Clear();
Series series = new Series("sample") { ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line, BorderWidth = 2, MarkerSize = 5, MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Square };
foreach (var p in data)
    series.Points.Add(p.Item1, p.Item2);
chart.Series.Add(series);
```

Comment: Hey Dmitry, I have one trouble with this chart, can You look at this: http://pl.tinypic.com/r/1zyfqlf/8

Comment: Not with the chart, but with a parsing. Try to specify an English culture as the second parameter of the `double.Parse` method as follows: `double.Parse(..., CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));`. I'm going to update the sample.

Comment: Thanks. I will try tomorrow :) Sorry for any problem, but I'm beginner.

Comment: Hey Dimitry, I dont understand Your sample with CultureInfo because it didnt works for me. I'm back to Your previously sample, and I change data inside .txt (example 1,5,6,7,3,7; not $GPRMC,2,A,5,7 etc) and it works for this values. I'll try to do something with code, because I need to read .txt with ($GPRMC, a, 6.6, 5 etc). Have You maybe any another idea instead "CultureInfo" ? Yes .. Your previously sample works only for int :)

Comment: This should work and it works for me. Nevertheless, parsing a `string` into the `double` is a separate question. Try to find the answer: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+double.Parse+FormatException).

Comment: Hey Dmitry, I have one a little problem, maybe You can help me once again? So in Your code, I want to do modification and chose min value in chart axes Y (I use this): chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = data1.Min();  but I have problem like: "Cannot implicity convert type 'System.Tuple<double> 'to 'double'.  || var minimalna1 = data1.Min(); -> this works but when I put "minimalna1" in ".AxisY.Minimum" I have the same problem with double to double..

Comment: Use `data1.Min(point => point.Item2)` to get `Y` values from datapoints instead of parameterless `data1.Min()`.

Comment: Hi @Dmitry, can You look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22879014/how-to-get-inside-private-static-tuple-and-use-numericupdown-to-change-math-rou

Answer (score 0):

I find answer for my question. I change "a litle" one line in code created by Dmitry. 
Here it is:

Previously code:

```
private static readonly CultureInfo EnglishCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
```

New code (just added **System.Globalization.** before CultureInfo) and it works on Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate), before change I have error "CultureInfo not found":

```
private static readonly System.Globalization.CultureInfo EnglishCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
```

I dont know why previously code dont work at me .. Maybe its by Visual System version. However all works now fine, and it's funny because now it works on previously code too, and the same with new change. I dont know whats going on, but all is fine.

Thanks Dmitry, for Your help.

PS. VERRY IMPORTANT (at the beginning we must declare this):

```
using System.Globalization;
```