# How to get inside private static Tuple, and use numericUpDown to change Math.Round

Tags: c#, gps, tuples, numericupdown

this is my part of code to parse a NMEA data (**source here** [Plot chart using values from richTextBox C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646101/plot-chart-using-values-from-richtextbox-c-sharp)) . This function get back latitude from richTextBox, and convert it to decimal notation. I need it, to plot charateristic from 4 another GPS module (to compare accuracy all four GPS).

This is my problem. I want to use a "numericUpDown" to change Math.Round (below I have value - 11). I cant get inside Tuple because I have error (I tried to do something, but it didnt work). Can anybody know, what should I do?

```
private static Tuple<double>[] szerokosc(string[] lines)
    {
        return Array.ConvertAll(lines, line =>
        {   
            string[] elems = line.Split(',');
            double we = 0.01 * double.Parse(elems[3], EnglishCulture);
            int stopnie = (int)we;
            double minuty = ((we - stopnie) * 100) / 60;
            double szerokosc_dziesietna = stopnie + minuty;
            return new Tuple<double>(Math.Round(szerokosc_dziesietna, 11));
        });
        ;
    }
```

I want something like this:

```
   return new Tuple<double>(Math.Round(szerokosc_dziesietna, round_value));
```

where (for example):

```
int round_value = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
```

and I declare:

```
numericUpDown1.Minimum = 1;
numericUpDown1.Maximum = 11;
```

Please help :).

Comment: "I tried to do something, but it didn't work".  What did you try, and why didn't it work?  What error messages (if any) did you get?  Also, is there a reason you're using 1-tuples?  Why not just return a `double[]` instead?

Comment: Hi, I try to do something like this: return new Tuple<double>(Math.Round(szerokosc_dziesietna, (int)numericUpDown2.Value )); - but it didnt works, I get back error "Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'OpenGPSdata.Form1.numericUpDown2'". Hmm I'm using Tuple, because I dont know how to use another method.

Comment: Is the `szerokosc` method in the code-behind of the form `Form1`?

Comment: Luke, I have another question, maybe You can tell me something about this. I delete in this code from line "private static Tuple<double>[] szerokosc(string[] lines)" word "static" so I have now "private  Tuple<double>[] szerokosc(string[] lines)" and I added "return new Tuple<double>(Math.Round(szerokosc_dziesietna, (int)numericUpDown2.Value));"  -> (int)numericUpDown2.Value - and it works, I can change now display accuracy on my chart. My question is: I delete "static" fromy my function, and all works. Now I dont know is "static" is important in my code,cause I'm beginner, but all works now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you figured out, and as I suspected but couldn't be sure as I didn't have all the code, the problem was caused by the `static` keyword in your method.  Removing it fixed the problem.

The `static` modifier is used to indicate that the method/property/field/etc. belongs to the class, rather than to instances of the class.  Inside a `static` method or property, you cannot use `this` to refer to the 'current' instance of the class, as `static` methods don't have a current instance.

In Windows Forms, the fields created for the various controls in the forms, such as your `numericUpDown2`, are always 'instance' fields, i.e. not `static`, so they belong to each individual instance of the form, rather than to the `Form1` class.  That way, if you have two different `Form1`s open at the same time, the corresponding controls in the two forms can have different values.  (You might only need to use one `Form1` in your application, but other forms in other applications may need to be used more than once.)  A `static` method in the `Form1` class cannot see any of these controls because it belongs to the `Form1` class, where an instance (i.e. non-static) method belongs to each individual form.  So a `static` method cannot see the controls because it can't know which form of possibly many the controls are in.

As you are a beginner, the advice I would give to you if you are unsure about whether you need to make a method `static` would be not to make the method `static`.  If a method makes no use of any instance-specific fields or methods, you can try making it `static` if you wish, and see if doing so introduces any compiler warnings.

Comment: Maybe my problem was funny (and my question about static), but I'm beginner, and I have 2 month to write a program for my studies, but I dont have a lot of time to learn all about C#. Happily I'm close to finish my program. Thank You very much for answer and help, I greet from Poland :).